# Clarification: Rudin Theorem 3.7: Subsequential limits are closed

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

[image]

My question is this:

> Why does Rudin use $\delta$ in this proof?

Would it not work just as well if $\forall i \ge1,$ $$x_{i}\in N_{2^{-(i+1)}}(q) \cap E^* $$
$$p_{n_i}\in N_{2^{-(i+1)}}(x_i) \cap \{p_n\}, n_i \gt n_{i-1}$$
$$\implies d(q,p_{n_i}) \le d(q,x_i) + d(x_i,p_{n_i}) < \frac{1}{2^{i+1}} +\frac{1}{2^{i+1}} = 2^{-i} $$

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of $\delta$ is to ensure our sequence isn't constant. That's really it, but you captured the most important point of the proof, that is we need to show $d(q,p_{n_i}) \to 0$